# Incorporate redux-thunk into mapDispatchToProps

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have an existing `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateThickness: (text, number) => {
    dispatch(updateDimension('thickness', text, number))
  }
})
```

But i now need to calculate volume and dispatch the result every time I `updateThickness`. Which essentially will be this:

```
let litres = calcVol(getState())
dispatch(updateVolume(litres))
```

Where `getState()` is the redux store. Which is why I'm adding `redux-thunk`. I have seen some `redux-thunk` usages in `mapStateToProps` but my use case is very different.

This is my attempt to udate `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateThickness: (text, number) => {
    dispatch(updateDimension('thickness', text, number))
    let litres = calcVol(getState())
    dispatch(updateVolume(litres))
  }
})
```

`getState()` is undefined though as I'm not incorporating redux-thunk correctly.

How do I correctly incorporate `redux-thunk` into `mapDispatchToProps`?

Comment: You may want to look into `selectors` within Redux. https://github.com/reactjs/reselect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateThickness` is not using redux-thunk. With redux-thunk, the action creator can return a function, which receives `dispatch` and `getState` as parameters.

So try this instead:

```
updateThickness: (text, number) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(updateDimension('thickness', text, number))
  let litres = calcVol(getState())
  dispatch(updateVolume(litres))
}
```

`updateThickness` is also a kind of action creator. Usually we separate the action creators:

```
const updateThickness = (text, number) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(updateDimension('thickness', text, number))
  let litres = calcVol(getState())
  dispatch(updateVolume(litres))
}
```

And you connect it like this:

```
connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { updateThickness } // can be a plain object
)(YourComponent)
```